# How can I solve this problem with GenyMotion?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I need to create an app that displays a number every time a button is clicked on, I've done my best and yet the emulator goes like "your app has stopped". I've been searching for the solution in internet but I can't figure out what the problem is. Could anyone help me? I've been stuck here for hours.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnSumar;
private TextView txtResultado;
private TextView txtLaboratorio;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    txtLaboratorio = findViewById(R.id.TVLaboratorio);
    btnSumar= findViewById(R.id.btnSumar);
    txtResultado= findViewById(R.id.TVResultado);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSumar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             int suma = Integer.valueOf(txtResultado.getText().toString());
            suma+=2;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I added that title because I was not allowed the original title "Your app has stopped". That's the message I get everytime I run the app. Apparently, everything is fine in the logcat section.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to initialize widgets before setting/binding layout to the the activity. This produces `NullPointerException`.

```
txtLaboratorio = findViewById(R.id.TVLaboratorio);
btnSumar = findViewById(R.id.btnSumar);
txtResultado = findViewById(R.id.TVResultado);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   // <<====== wrong
```

Add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` part before initializing widgets.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   // <<====== this part
txtLaboratorio = findViewById(R.id.TVLaboratorio);
btnSumar = findViewById(R.id.btnSumar);
txtResultado = findViewById(R.id.TVResultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

`You are not initiate controls before initialize layout(view).` So issue with your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` you have to define your view instant after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

**Try this code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnSumar;
private TextView txtResultado;
private TextView txtLaboratorio;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtLaboratorio = findViewById(R.id.TVLaboratorio);
    btnSumar= findViewById(R.id.btnSumar);
    txtResultado= findViewById(R.id.TVResultado);
    btnSumar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             int suma = Integer.valueOf(txtResultado.getText().toString());
            suma+=2;
        }
    });
}
}
```